# Making two objects rotate at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, rotation

So I have this assignment where I have to make two objects move at the same time. I know that I should use thread class but i am not sure how to do it. My project has two files. The first one has main method and implements fan object.Here it is:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;


    public class DrawArcs extends JFrame {
    public DrawArcs() {
        setTitle("DrawArcs");
        add(new ArcsPanel());
     }

     /** Main method */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawArcs frame = new DrawArcs();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(new StillClock());


     }
    }

    class ArcsPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
        int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
        int radius = (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

        int x = xCenter - radius;
        int y = yCenter - radius;

        g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 30);
        g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90, 30);
        g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180, 30);
        g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270, 30);
    }
 }
```

My second file includes implementation of the clock class.

```
public class StillClock  extends JPanel {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;


    public StillClock() {
        setCurrentTime();
    }


    public StillClock(int hour, int minute, int second) {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
    }
////there are setters and getters here
 .
 .
 . 
////

    @Override /** Draw the clock */
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Initialize clock parameters
        int clockRadius =
                (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.8 * 0.5);
        int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
        int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;

        // Draw circle
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawOval(xCenter - clockRadius, yCenter - clockRadius,
                2 * clockRadius, 2 * clockRadius);
        g.drawString("12", xCenter - 5, yCenter - clockRadius + 12);
        g.drawString("9", xCenter - clockRadius + 3, yCenter + 5);
        g.drawString("3", xCenter + clockRadius - 10, yCenter + 3);
        g.drawString("6", xCenter - 3, yCenter + clockRadius - 3);

        // Draw second hand
        int sLength = (int)(clockRadius * 0.8);
        int xSecond = (int)(xCenter + sLength *
                Math.sin(second * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));
        int ySecond = (int)(yCenter - sLength *
                Math.cos(second * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(xCenter, yCenter, xSecond, ySecond);

        // Draw minute hand
        int mLength = (int)(clockRadius * 0.65);
        int xMinute = (int)(xCenter + mLength *
                Math.sin(minute * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));
        int yMinute = (int)(yCenter - mLength *
                Math.cos(minute * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(xCenter, yCenter, xMinute, yMinute);

        // Draw hour hand
        int hLength = (int)(clockRadius * 0.5);
        int xHour = (int)(xCenter + hLength *
                Math.sin((hour % 12 + minute / 60.0) * (2 * Math.PI / 12)));
        int yHour = (int)(yCenter - hLength *
                Math.cos((hour % 12 + minute / 60.0) * (2 * Math.PI / 12)));
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawLine(xCenter, yCenter, xHour, yHour);
    }

    public void setCurrentTime() {
        // Construct a calendar for the current date and time
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

        // Set current hour, minute and second
        this.hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        this.minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        this.second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
}
```

So my question is how do I make both fan and clock rotate at the same time?

Here is how it looks the you run the code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxo7D.png)

Comment: Start by having a look at Swing Timer to update the states of the you’re depending on

Comment: what are you trying to rotate, what is happening,  why is this incorrect and what should happen?

Comment: @vandale I am trying to rotate legs of the clock and fan plates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're actually asking two questions:

1. How to animate a number of objects
2. How to rotate a object (as the clock doesn't need to be rotated)

## Rotating

Rotating is relatively easy in 2D Graphics, with a number of possible options. I'm going to use a `AffineTransform` as a personal preference.

We need to add a couple of things to the `ArcsPanel`, we need a `angle`, which represents the current angle of rotation, and a `delta`, which represents the amount of movement on each animation pass...

```
public static class ArcsPanel extends JPanel {

    protected static final float DELTA = 1.0f;
    private float angle = 0;
```

With this information, we can simply modify the `paintComponent` method to support the `angle` property and apply the `AffineTransform`

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
    int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
    int radius = (int) (Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

    g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(angle), xCenter, yCenter));

    int x = xCenter - radius;
    int y = yCenter - radius;

    g2d.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 30);
    g2d.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90, 30);
    g2d.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180, 30);
    g2d.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270, 30);
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

## Animating a number of objects

Despite what you might think, you don't want more threads, you actually only want one.  This one thread will notify all the objects you want to be updated that they should update their animatable states.  This thread doesn't care "how" they do that, it only drives the process.  Equally, your objects don't care "how" the engine works, only that it will notify them on a regular bases.

Now, Swing is both single threaded and not thread safe. This raises a number of issues when dealing with threads.  You can't run long running or blocking operations within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread and you shouldn't update the state of the UI from outside the EDT either.

For simplicity, a Swing `Timer` is a perfect choice, as it waits off the EDT, but triggers it's updates in the EDT.

First, we need some way for the engine to tell other objects that they should update themselves.  Sure you can simply maintain a direct reference to the other components, but this both increases the coupling between objects, it also limits the engines re-usability.

Instead, we define a simple interface...

```
public interface Animatable {
    public void updateAnimatedState();
}
```

All objects that want to be notified will implement this `interface` and can register with the engine

```
public class Engine {

    private List<Animatable> animatables;
    private Timer timer;

    public Engine() {
        animatables = new ArrayList<>(4);
        timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (Animatable animatable : animatables) {
                    animatable.updateAnimatedState();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void add(Animatable animatable) {
        animatables.add(animatable);
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```

Now, all we need to do is update the two components...

```
public static class ArcsPanel extends JPanel implements Animatable {
    //...
    @Override
    public void updateAnimatedState() {
        angle += DELTA;
        repaint();
    }
}

public class StillClock extends JPanel implements Animatable {
    //...

    @Override
    public void updateAnimatedState() {
        setCurrentTime();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

You'll note that I've modified your code slightly so that both components now extend from `JPanel`, extending from `JFrame` is very limiting and generally discouraged.

Finally, we just need to set it all up...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                ArcsPanel arcPanel = new ArcsPanel();
                StillClock clockPanel = new StillClock();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
                frame.add(arcPanel);
                frame.add(clockPanel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                Engine engine = new Engine();
                engine.add(arcPanel);
                engine.add(clockPanel);
                engine.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## Runnable example...

And because I know how confusing a bunch of out-of-context code snippets can be...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                ArcsPanel arcPanel = new ArcsPanel();
                StillClock clockPanel = new StillClock();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
                frame.add(arcPanel);
                frame.add(clockPanel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                Engine engine = new Engine();
                engine.add(arcPanel);
                engine.add(clockPanel);
                engine.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class Engine {

        private List<Animatable> animatables;
        private Timer timer;

        public Engine() {
            animatables = new ArrayList<>(4);
            timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (Animatable animatable : animatables) {
                        animatable.updateAnimatedState();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void add(Animatable animatable) {
            animatables.add(animatable);
        }

        public void start() {
            timer.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    public interface Animatable {

        public void updateAnimatedState();
    }

    public static class ArcsPanel extends JPanel implements Animatable {

        protected static final float DELTA = 1.0f;
        private float angle = 0;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
            int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
            int radius = (int) (Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

            g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(angle), xCenter, yCenter));

            int x = xCenter - radius;
            int y = yCenter - radius;

            g2d.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 30);
            g2d.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90, 30);
            g2d.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180, 30);
            g2d.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270, 30);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateAnimatedState() {
            angle += DELTA;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public class StillClock extends JPanel implements Animatable {

        private int hour;
        private int minute;
        private int second;

        public StillClock() {
            setCurrentTime();
        }

        public StillClock(int hour, int minute, int second) {
            this.hour = hour;
            this.minute = minute;
            this.second = second;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            // Initialize clock parameters
            int clockRadius
                            = (int) (Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.8 * 0.5);
            int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
            int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;

            // Draw circle
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawOval(xCenter - clockRadius, yCenter - clockRadius,
                            2 * clockRadius, 2 * clockRadius);
            g.drawString("12", xCenter - 5, yCenter - clockRadius + 12);
            g.drawString("9", xCenter - clockRadius + 3, yCenter + 5);
            g.drawString("3", xCenter + clockRadius - 10, yCenter + 3);
            g.drawString("6", xCenter - 3, yCenter + clockRadius - 3);

            // Draw second hand
            int sLength = (int) (clockRadius * 0.8);
            int xSecond = (int) (xCenter + sLength
                            * Math.sin(second * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));
            int ySecond = (int) (yCenter - sLength
                            * Math.cos(second * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawLine(xCenter, yCenter, xSecond, ySecond);

            // Draw minute hand
            int mLength = (int) (clockRadius * 0.65);
            int xMinute = (int) (xCenter + mLength
                            * Math.sin(minute * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));
            int yMinute = (int) (yCenter - mLength
                            * Math.cos(minute * (2 * Math.PI / 60)));
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawLine(xCenter, yCenter, xMinute, yMinute);

            // Draw hour hand
            int hLength = (int) (clockRadius * 0.5);
            int xHour = (int) (xCenter + hLength
                            * Math.sin((hour % 12 + minute / 60.0) * (2 * Math.PI / 12)));
            int yHour = (int) (yCenter - hLength
                            * Math.cos((hour % 12 + minute / 60.0) * (2 * Math.PI / 12)));
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawLine(xCenter, yCenter, xHour, yHour);
        }

        public void setCurrentTime() {
            // Construct a calendar for the current date and time
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

            // Set current hour, minute and second
            this.hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            this.minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            this.second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateAnimatedState() {
            setCurrentTime();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to run your Runnable Example i get an error: Could not find or load main class DrawArcs. I am not sure how to fix it, although my file name is DrawArcs.java, so it is probably related to this.

Comment: There is no `DrawArcs` class in my example

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it by changing Test class to DrawArcs class. Thank you for your answer!